# How to convert binary to decimal(39,0) in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have ipv6 addresses stored in decimal(39,0) unsigned format.

I need to query the database. I'm using INET6_ATON() which converts ipv6 to binary. Now I need to convert that binary to decimal(39,0).

Is this possible in pure MySQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, is possible. Because `DECIMAL` representation of IPv6 is bigger than maximum 64-bit integer (18,446,744,073,709,551,615), you must split the 'string' up to 16 characters and then to join them together:

example table:

```
mysql> select * from ip_table;
+----+-----------------------------------------+
| id | ipv6                                    |
+----+-----------------------------------------+
|  1 | 2001:db8:a0b:12f0::1                    |
|  2 | 3731:54:65fe:2::a7                      |
|  3 | FE80:0000:0000:0000:0202:B3FF:FE1E:8329 |
|  4 | FE80::0202:B3FF:FE1E:8329               |
+----+-----------------------------------------+
4 rows in set
```

SQL statement:

```
select id,
(
cast(conv(substr(HEX(INET6_ATON(t.`ipv6`)), 1, 16), 16, 10) as decimal(65))*18446744073709551616 +
cast(conv(substr(HEX(INET6_ATON(t.`ipv6`)), 17, 16), 16, 10) as decimal(65)) 
) as converted
from ip_table t
```

result:

```
+----+-----------------------------------------+
| id | converted                               |
+----+-----------------------------------------+
|  1 | 42540766414390830568948465903729639425  |
|  2 | 73361969000969283948743196392239923367  |
|  3 | 338288524927261089654163772891438416681 |
|  4 | 338288524927261089654163772891438416681 |
+----+-----------------------------------------+
4 rows in set
```

Note that last two IPs are the same, I've put them in different format in order to test is the script works properly.